# Calculate Average ,Minimum and Maximum of sold column with Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server, powerbi-custom-visuals

I would like to calculate the average year, min and max of the measure `[Retrait Inf 20M]`
I used like measure:
`[Retrait Inf 20M]`: it's the column where the withdrawl is less than 20000
`[Nbre de jours annuel]`: where I calculate the numbre of days on my date column per year
I have the same value for the min max and average. It looks incorrect
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eb9dk.png)

I create measures with Dax:

```
Min Retrait inf 20M = CALCULATE(MINX(Mesures,Mesures[Retrait Inf 20M]))
Max Retrait inf 20M = CALCULATE(MAXX(Mesures,Mesures[Retrait Inf 20M]))
Moyenne Annuelle RTR inf 20M = CALCULATE(DIVIDE([Retrait Inf 20M],[Nbre de jours annuel]))
Nbre de jours annuel = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(teller[date]),teller[année]=2022 || teller[année]=2023)
Retrait Inf 20M = CALCULATE(SUM(teller[amount_local]), FILTER(teller, teller[amount_local] <= 20000),FILTER(teller,teller[type_transaction]=="retrait"))
```

Comment: Can you share a .csv with dummy data?